# Tracing back javascript calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-debugger

In my chrome console, I am trying to understand what are the steps that lead to the call of some `javascript` file. 
Indeed, when I import a file from my computer after clicking on an input file tag, some javascript file is called, but I don't know which method called it. How can I trace it back in my debugger (chrome-console) ?

Edit :

The plugin I am working on is here : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. When  clicking on the add-file button, the file `load-image.min.js is called` (in the section network of the chrome debugger) and I don't know how it is called exactly

Comment: There's a section on the right that shows the stack trace when you're stopped at an error or breakpoint, isn't that the information you need?

Comment: @Barmar not exactly, in fact I notice now that this file must be some ajax call because I see it in the network section of my debugger. But I don't know  what triggered this ajax call...

Comment: It could be using something like `.loadScript()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes but I want to localize it in the code (I am working on a plugin so the code is quite huge... )

Comment: Could you post a relevant snippet from the file that's 'calling' the mystery script?

Comment: @CharlesMarsh you can see it here : `http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/`. When you import the file clicking on the `add-file` button, you'll see that the ajax call of the file `load-image.min.js` (in the section `network` of the chrome debugger)

Comment: When I use View Source I see the line `<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Barmar indeed this file is loaded when the page is loaded. But it is called again when I import for example some image from my desktop. Why is it loaded another time and how it is called ?

Comment: I don't see it showing up again in the Network tab. But it's also saying that the upload server is unavailable, I don't know if that's related.

Comment: If you think it's an AJAX call, you can set an XHR breakpoint that matches the URL.

Answer (score 2):

First off, know that when you "call" a JavaScript file (by which I think you mean "import"), no specific function will *inherently* be triggered. If you want any function to be triggered on load, you need to call that function in the global space of the JavaScript file. Often, this is done by creating a single, self-invoked function. For example, this code will define a function named 'foo' and call it whenever the JavaScript file is loaded:

```js
(function foo() {
   ...
})();
```

This would also be feasible:

```js
function foo() {
  ...
}
foo();
```

In terms of the Chrome developer tools (opened with Ctrl+Shift+J), you have a few options. Closest to what you describe is the 'Profiles' tool. Click on that tab, choose 'Collect JavaScript CPU Profile', and run the profiler for a few sections. It will return with a list of functions executed by your CPU and the time spent within them.

Comment: @MESSIAH indeed. IN fact, I notice now that this file must be some ajax call because I see it in the `network` section of my debugger

Comment: So you're wondering how a particular script might end up being loaded on your web page?

Comment: I want to localize the peace of code that made this file called when I imported some image.

Comment: Sorry, the use case is still not clear to me. From one JavaScript file, you're importing an image, and then you're noticing that a function from a separate JavaScript file is being called?

Comment: if i am not wrong,you probably want to know the behind the scenes of javascript interpretation..what exactly happens when an onclick,input file whatevr is triggered...??

Comment: @MESSIAH yes indeed !

Comment: I tried to undertand this..but it will take fresh pair of eyes..i am too tired now...http://www.quora.com/JavaScript/How-does-a-JavaScript-engine-work

Comment: if you want,you can also see the source code of chromes v8 engine and mozillas spidermonkey!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch an AJAX call, use the **XHR Breakpoints** section of the Javascript debugger. Click on the **+** to add a breakpoint, and enter `load-image` in the prompt for a string to match against the URL.